# How to add more than 32 routes to isc-dhcp-server and separate them to 2 fields?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, isc-dhcp, dhcp-option

Is there any way to add long list routes to server? Actually now I can add only 32 routes because we have only 1 octet for them. After adding more than 32 routes I received "Malformed packet" by Wireshark.

[image]

But Iam sure that I can add more than 32 routes because of this pic

[image]

Which parameter in isc-dhcp-server may help me divide 121/249 option to two fields in packet?

Now it looks like that for 43 routes

```
option classless-routes-win code 249 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option classless-routes-win 24, 192,168,100, 192,168,100,2,
                            .., ...,...,..., ...,...,...,.,
                            24, 192,168,99,  192,168,100,2;
```

Comment: If you need more that 32 static routes on your machine, perhaps you can try aggregating different subnets into larger blocks, or instead run a routing protocol on the box so it dynamically learns them.

Comment: @Tommiie I think I shouldnt change any parameters on client. I really thought there is some string that I should add in dhcpd.conf on server for separate 249 options as I shown on pic above. maybe `option dhcp-option-overload 3` , but that is not something that I need. Im confused.